# How to make the layout scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

That's edit form in My application,
there's one button left after "Simpan Perubahan" button.
How to make my form scrollable and make the last button visible and clickable?

I do not know much about layouts.

#### code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
        android:text="ID Objek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_obj_id"
        android:editable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Nama Objek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_obj_nama"
        android:editable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Detail Objek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_obj_det"
        android:editable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Koordinat Objek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_obj_long"
        android:editable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_obj_lat"
        android:editable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_obj_submit"
        android:text="Simpan Perubahan"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_obj_back"
        android:text="Simpan Perubahan"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What should i do to my xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout should look like

```
<LinearLayout vertical>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout vertical>
        ... here are your fields ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout horizontal>
    ... here are your buttons ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what's the different between vertical and horizontal <LinearLayout> ?

Comment: @Falmesino in vertical layout elements are arranged from top to down like on your screenshot, in horizontal they go from left to right on the same level

Comment: I also use a relative layout to ensure that my buttons are at the bottom of the screen, but that is a minor point.

Answer (score 1):

Use ScrollView component in the xml. [example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can make List.builder or listview or use scrollable layout using scroll widget in flutter. below is a code you can customized according to your need i did it with List.builder

List litems = ["1","2","3","4"];

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "LeaderBoard",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.trending_up,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Person",
                    )),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Text(
                    "Score",
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: litems.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return new Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(litems[index]),
                    title: Text(litems[index]),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}